# How to override Tapestry's two-way boolean coercion with three-way one?

Tags: java, null, boolean, tapestry, coercion

Consider this case.

You have a class which you cannot change or extend in any way.

```
public class Foo {
    ...
    private Boolean bar;
    ...
}
```

You need to edit the fields of that class via `BeanEditor`, but the logic behind that class allows and uses the fact that `Boolean` can have, so to say, 3 states: **null**, **true** and **false**.

Tapestry will, however, give you a checkbox with only 2 options, **true** or **false**.

So, people online suggest that you convert your `Boolean` type property to `BooleanExtendedEnum` type property which could represent three way logic.

```
public enum BooleanExtendedEnum {
    UNDEFINED(null),
    TRUE(Boolean.TRUE),
    FALSE(Boolean.FALSE);

    private Boolean booleanValue;

    private static Map<Boolean, BooleanExtendedEnum> booleanToExtendedMap = new HashMap<Boolean, BooleanExtendedEnum>();


    static {
        for (BooleanExtendedEnum be : BooleanExtendedEnum.values()) {
            booleanToExtendedMap.put(be.booleanValue, be);
        }
    }

    private BooleanExtendedEnum(Boolean booleanValue) {
        this.booleanValue = booleanValue;
    }

    public Boolean getBooleanValue() {
        return booleanValue;
    }

    public static BooleanExtendedEnum getBooleanExtendedValue(Boolean booleanInput) {
        return booleanToExtendedMap.get(booleanInput);
    }

}
```

Since you cannot change your `Foo` class, you'll need to create a coercer for `Boolean <=> BooleanExtendedEnum`.

```
Coercion<Boolean, BooleanExtendedEnum> threeWayBooleanToExtended = new Coercion<Boolean, BooleanExtendedEnum>() {
    @Override
    public BooleanExtendedEnum coerce(Boolean input) {
        if (input == null) {
            return BooleanExtendedEnum.UNDEFINED;
        } else {
            return BooleanExtendedEnum.getBooleanExtendedEnumValue(input);
        }
    }
};

Coercion<BooleanExtendedEnum, Boolean> threeWayExtendedToBoolean = new Coercion<BooleanExtendedEnum, Boolean>() {
    @Override
    public Boolean coerce(BooleanExtendedEnum input) {
        if (input == null) {
            return null;
        } else {
            return input.getBooleanValue();
        }
    }
};

configuration.add(new CoercionTuple<Boolean, BooleanExtendedEnum>(Boolean.class, BooleanExtendedEnum.class, threeWayBooleanToExtended));
configuration.add(new CoercionTuple<BooleanExtendedEnum, Boolean>(BooleanExtendedEnum.class, Boolean.class, threeWayExtendedToBoolean));
```

Let's assume you have done something as simple as this in your `BeanEditor` in your `tml`:

```
<p:bar>
    <div class="t-beaneditor-row">
        <label>Bar Value</label>
        <t:select t:id="fooBar" t:value="foo.bar" t:model="booleanExtendedSelectModel" t:blankOption="NEVER"/>
    </div>
</p:bar>
```

... and provided the `SelectModel` like this:

```
public SelectModel getBooleanExtendedSelectModel() {
    return new EnumSelectModel(BooleanExtendedEnum.class, messages);
}
```

Tapestry will create a drop-down list with three options

- `Undefined`
- `True`
- `False`

However, the real Boolean values it will coerce those displayed values  to will be

- `Undefined` -> **true**
- `True` -> **true**
- `False` -> **false**

How can one achieve the desired effect (`Undefined` -> **null**), with limitations of not changing the class or wrapping it in another class which has `Boolean` type fields replaced with `BooleanExtendedEnum` type ones or using any other "hacky" solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "glue" between the BeanEditor and the backing bean is the [BeanModel](http://tapestry.apache.org/current/apidocs/org/apache/tapestry5/beaneditor/BeanModel.html). BeanModels are created by the BeanModelSource which in turn uses [PropertyConduitSource](http://tapestry.apache.org/current/apidocs/org/apache/tapestry5/services/PropertyConduitSource.html).

It's quite simple to decorate the PropertyConduitSource to use `Ternary` instead of `Boolean`.

eg

```
public class MyAppModule {
    public PropertyConduitSource decoratePropertyConduitSource(final PropertyConduitSource old) {
       return new PropertyConduitSource() {
          public PropertyConduit create(Class rootType, String expression) { 
             PropertyConduit conduit = old.create(rootType, expression);

             // you cound also check for conduit.getAnnotation(AllowNull.class) 
             // and then annotate your bean properties for a more granular approach
             if (Boolean.class.equals(conduit.getPropertyType()) {
                return new TernaryPropertyConduit(conduit);
             }
             return conduit;
          }
       }
    }
}

public class TernaryPropertyConduit implements PropertyConduit {
   private PropertyConduit delegate;

   public getPropertyType() { return Ternary.class };

   public set(Object instance, Object value) {
      delegate.set(instance, ((Ternary) value).asBoolean());
   }

   public get(Object) {
      Boolean bValue = (Boolean) delegate.get(instance);
      return Ternary.valueOf(instance);
   }
}
```

Comment: This looks interesting, do you maybe have a link to some example?
I believe I understand what you're saying here, but since I've never done this before, I'd like to be sure :)

Comment: I've never done it either. I've given you a head start with the decorate method but you'll need to implement TernaryBeanModelSource.

Comment: Added changes. Much simpler now

Comment: Ah, sry, didnt see you added changes, tyvm :)
I was going in the similar direction, but yeah, this is much simpler :)

Seems I still have a lot to learn about Tapestry. As usual, my big thanks :D

Comment: One question, regarding your last edit about `conduit.getAnnotation`. I don't seem to have `AllowNull` class. Should that be my own, or does it come with Tapestry?

Comment: It's a custom annotation that you can create and name how you like

Answer (score 1):

You could add a property to your page and use a custom block.

```
public enum Ternary {
    TRUE(Boolean.TRUE), FALSE(Boolean.FALSE), UNDEFINED(null);

    public static Ternary valueOf(Boolean value) { ... }
    public Boolean asBoolean() { ... }
}

public class MyPage {
    @Property
    private Foo foo;

    public Ternary getTernaryBar() {
       return Ternary.valueOf(foo.getBar());
    }

    public void setTernaryBar(Ternary tBar) {
       foo.setBar(tBar.asBoolean());
    }
}

<t:beaneditor t:id="foo" exclude="bar" add="ternaryBar">
    <p:ternaryBar>
       <t:label for="ternaryBar"/>
       <t:select t:id="ternaryBar" />
    </p:ternaryBar>
</t:beaneditor>
```

Comment: I understand the solution, but given that I have quite a few Foo classes on quite a few pages, that isn't the solution that I'm looking for. Still, thx for the effort :)